# Salesforce.com REST API - Removing object field's value

Tags: rest, salesforce

In the Salesforce.com REST API sObjects PATCH command, how do I remove an object's field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, the following methods work:

- `{"FieldName" : ""}`
- `{"FieldName" : null}`